# Button takes you to drilldowns in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

Is there a way to have two buttons act as the drill down/up functions for a pie chart using `HighCharts`?

In other words in addition to clicking on the slices, a user could click on a button to switch between the two charts? Like:

[image]

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ng1kvmxh/25/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to refer to particular point and call doDrilldown() function.

Example:
- http://jsfiddle.net/ng1kvmxh/27/

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

   chart.series[0].data[4].doDrilldown();
});

$('#btn2').click(function(){
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    chart.series[0].data[4].doDrilldown();
});
```

Comment: where do you specify the data? I'm confused on what `chart.series[0].data[4]` returns

Comment: Is there a way to remove the highcharts "back" button and just use these buttons to toggle between the graphs?

Comment: Maybe better is resign from drilldown and destroy chart/create new one?